# single login page in devise gem for two type of user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Using Devise gem :-

in my application i have two type user
1) Company
2) Employee

i have two separate model for both user and i want to give single sign-in page for both user

i already generate different views for both user using devise but then also i need single sign-in.

so how it is possible please help me out...!!!!!!!!!

i try this:-
controllers/compnaies/sessions_controller.rb

```
def create
  @employee = Employee.new
  @company = Company.new
  if @company.email_exist?(params[:company][:email])
    super
  elsif @employee.email_exist?(params[:company][:email])
    params[:employee]=params[:company]
    redirect_to employee_session_path(params)
  end
end
```

employee_session_path is the path of employees's sessions create method but it always call new method of employees's sessions

controllers/employees/sessions_controller.rb

```
def create
 super
end
```

email_exist? method check the email id in both model which is provided by any of user

in my model:

company.rb

```
def email_exist?(email)
  if Company.find_by(email: email)
   return true
  end
end
```

employee.rb

```
def email_exist?(email)
  if Employee.find_by(email: email)
   return true
  end
end
```

Thanks in advance...!!!!!!!!

Comment: try this, this may help https://gist.github.com/jeremyw/5319386

Comment: CanCan is good gem for authentication, you can always use that. Here  you can see a good implementation of that http://wiki.summercode.com/rails_authentication_with_devise_and_cancan

Answer (score 0):

CanCan and Rolify seems to be the combination stack you are looking for to solve your problems here are the link to the github pages: 
Rolify https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify

CanCan https://github.com/ryanb/cancan and the Railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan

Let me know if you need any help